# How to pass an array of unknown dimension as a method argument?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, methods

Suppose I would like to create a method that takes 1-D or 2-D arrays as argument (for the present time, it wouldn't make sense to accept higher dimension arrays). I know I can simply create two different methods, but I'd like to keep just one, for sake of keeping my code short.

Is there a way to create such a method?

Comment: How do you expect the method to consume such argument? Should it for example have an if statement to check if it is a 1d or 2d array?

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense as the code inside would be fundamentally different depending on the dimensionality of the array. What exactly is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you not use method overloading?

Comment: Can you just use 2-d array always, and conditionally use only 1 side?  I would think most cases like this would have quite different implementation based on the number of dimensions in the array parameter.

Comment: @YacoubMassad That is correct- in the method I would have an "if/then" statement and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can simply create two different methods, but I'd like to keep just one, for sake of keeping my code short.

Define the processing that is common to both cases, and create a third (probably private) method that performs that calculation.

Create method overloads that accept both types of arrays, and have them call the third method to perform the processing that both cases have in common.

Comment: I didn't know about method overloading until I just read about it now (if you couldn't tell, I'm still new to a lot of this). Thank you for your suggestion.